# tengo un problema con este codigo, estoy haciendo un proyecto en unity usando csharp

Tags: c#, unity3d, game

estoy haciendo un sistema para recojer armas, el cual consiste en que si yo paso encima de un arma el `GameObject` se destruye y activa una de las armas que ya estaba en la mano, dando la ilusion de que se recogio, pero al intentar darle play me da este error en la linea 25,24:

> error cs1061: CogerArmas does not contain a definition for ActivarArmar and no accesible extension method ActivarArmar accepting a first argument of type CogerArmas could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Aqui dejo el codigo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActivarArmaPersonaje : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CogerArmas cogerArmas;
    public int numeroArma;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cogerArmas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CogerArmas>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
        cogerArmas.ActivarArmar(numeroArma);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Aqui esta el codigo CogerArmas

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CogerArmas : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] armas;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    public void ActivarArma(int numero)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < armas.Length; i++)
        {
            armas[i].SetActive(false);
        }

        armas[numero].SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tu script `CogerArmas` no tiene un método `ActivarArmar()`. Tal vez quisiste escribir `ActivarArmas` con S? Algo muy importante a la hora de programar es revisar lo que escribimos, y sobre todo, leer los mensajes de error... a estas alturas de la historia, los códigos de error ya no son indescifrables si no que indican exactamente el problema. No tienes más que traducirlo si no sabes inglés (cosa que te sugiero que aprendas si quieres programar, por lo menos a nivel técnico)

Comment: y tal vez nos quieras compartir el código de `CogerArmas` para tener un [mcve]

Comment: yo vi un tutorial y en el tutorial lo hacian asi, "ActivarArmar", no "ActivarArmas" aqui dejo el link si van a ver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23NSAcE785E

Answer (score 1):

En tu código en el método `OnTriggerEnter` estás llamando a un método que no existe en tu script `CogerArmas`:

```
cogerArmas.ActivarArmar(numeroArma);
```

cámbialo por

```
cogerArmas.ActivarArma(numeroArma);
```

de esa manera llamas al método que sí tienes definido en tu script `CogerArmas`:

```
public void ActivarArma(int numero)
```

Comment: gracias eso si me ayudo

Comment: si solucionó tu problema puedes dar click en el icono a la izquierda, si solamente te ayudó da click en el botón de flecha hacia arriba para poder compartir esta respuesta en caso de que alguien tenga un problema similar. De igual manera te recomiendo hacer el tour por el sitio si tienes alguna duda de como funciona. Saludos.